# Eclipse plugin display text which is of any language

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

i am new to eclipse plugin development. i created a plugin which loads a unicode saved text file from the folder & displays it on a dialog & also setting it for the Label. If it is, in an English Language, everything is working fine. But if i try to load any other language text, it is displaying empty. How can i get through this.

Here is some code on how i am displaying it on dialog:

```
    Shell shell = Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell();
    // Loading the file by creating the assets folder & Temp.txt file inside
    // Eclipse Plugin
    URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("assets/Temp.txt"), null);

    URL fileUrl = null;
    try {
        fileUrl = FileLocator.toFileURL(url);
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }

    File file = new File(fileUrl.getPath());

    String Message = "";
    try {
        if (file.exists()) {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new FileReader(file));
            String str;

            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {

                if (str.contains(LanguageSelected)) {
                    System.out.println(str);
                    Message = Message + "\n" + str;
                }
            }

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Creating the dialog
    Shell dialog = new Shell(shell, SWT.DIALOG_TRIM | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    ...
    // Adding Label to dialog
    Label LabelMessage = new Label(dialog, SWT.LEFT);
    GridData data = new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL);
    data.horizontalSpan = 6;
    // Adding Message to the dialog
    LabelMessage.setLayoutData(data);
    LabelMessage.setBackground(new Color(null, 255, 255, 255)); // White
    LabelMessage.setText(Message);
```

Comment: You have not included enough information for anyone to be able to help you. How are you loading the file? How are you displaying it?

Comment: Please check, I have edited it.

Comment: could you post the content of your Temp.txt file? looks like you have one file with different language content in it? and str.contains(LanguageSelected) is filtering it

Answer (score 0):

In your launch configuration, make sure you are setting the `-nl` parameter to the language you want to display.  See http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html for information.